# Parsing JSON With Requests library In Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I am not able to parse the json correctly. I am using requests library to parse. I am getting the whole json on my local host but not able to parse individual items.

this is my header of json on that I have in my json url.

```
[{"id": 4, "company_name": "Ta..........oor guide. "}, {" id ": 5," company_n........is campaign. \ n "}]
```

my `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    import requests
    import json
    api_request = requests.get('https://us-c..../content_all/json')

    try:
        api = json.loads(api_request.content)

    except Exception as e:
        api = "Error"

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'api':api})
```

this is my `home.html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{{ api }}   

{% endblock %}
```

when I am trying only api in `home.html` it is showing the whole json but when I am trying this

```
{{ api.company_name }}     #company_name is key in my json
```

A blank page is coming. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `api` is a list of dicts, not a dict directly.

So to access `company_name` of one of the dicts you can do

```
{{ api.0.company_name }}      {% this is the first element of the list %}
{{ api.1.company_name }}      {% this is the second element of the list %}
```

Or itertate over them

```
{% for elem in api %}
    {{ elem.company_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON does not seem to be valid.
There are 2 opening curly braces (`{`) but only 1 closing counter part (`}`), so the data parsing should fail because of this.

Check that the JSON you got is really the correct content you should get. Maybe the source is sending wrong data? Or you just copy-pasted it wrong into the question here?

Comment: I edited my question, I updated with the json source file which I have in the url.